# i have to click button twice to make it work

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager

i have a veiwpager that has (say 5) pages and in each page there is a textview. i also have a button to change the textsize of the text. the code works but i have to click button twice to make it work.

I researched and found that first time the button gets focused so i also tried adding android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to my button xml layout but same thing happening. i don't know why it is behaving like this.

i think this might be because i m using veiwpager so the view is already instantiated and after i click button once the text on the first page does not change however when i swipe to the third page i can see the change.

I have tried everything and now i am losing my moral. Please can someone spare 5 min to tell me what am i doing wrong here.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv,situation;
int recsize;
ViewPager viewPager;
SlideSrt adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button size = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

     adapter = new SlideSrt(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    size.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            situation.setTextSize(30);
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            recsize =1;
        }
    });

}


 private class SlideSrt extends PagerAdapter {
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;


        String s1 = "Text1";
        String s2 = "Text2";
        String s3 = "Text3";
        String s4 = "Text4";
        String s5 = "Text5";

        String allsrt[] = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5};

        SlideSrt(Context context) {
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return allsrt.length;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


            View itemview;
            itemview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
            situation = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


          situation.setText("position: "+position);

          if (recsize == 1){
                situation.setTextSize(30);
          }

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemview,0);

            return itemview;

        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `TextView situation` is part of activity or adapter?

Comment: adapter. textview situation is in pager.xml which my pageradapter is inflating.

Comment: can you debug and check if it is calling onClick method for first time click or not?

Comment: k. wait. i m trying to find out how to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

Set `recsize =1;`

Before Calling

```
viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Lol its working now. i dont know why though. i feel like a noob. thanks for the help bro

Answer (score 1):

yes the problem is viewpager. It creats at-least one page in advance depends on `offScreenLimit`, so when you are on page 0, It may have already loaded page 1 and your situation variable 'll be pointing to textView of the second page in the memory. and hence increasing the size for that page instead of current page.

Solution - 
Take an int set it to the default value of textsize, in `onclickListener` change the deafult value to 30. Set `onPageChangeListener` for your pager. Define situation variable inside the instantiate method itself, set some tag value for that say R.id.textView1 . In the `onPageSelected` method of `onPagechangeListener` check if the default value of textsize has been changed to 30, from pager `findViewByTag(R.id.textView1)` cast it to textView and set the size for that textView.